# usb_cam package and head_camera.yaml missing

Tags: calibration, usb-cam, camera-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am new to ROS. I have been trying to do usb camera integration into a robotics project at our university's lab.
I will write the steps i did and the errors that i got.

1. I went into my ~/catkin_ws/src folder and i ran

   git clone https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam
2. Then I went into my ~/catkin_ws folder and ran

   source /devel/setup.bash
3. Then I ran

   roscore
4. Then I ran

   roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch
5. This was the output
   ... logging to /home/submetu/.ros/log/1fd73732-55ad-11e6-a65d-d8fc93edb7dc/roslaunch-submetu-9724.log
   Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
   Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
   Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://submetu:40095/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /image_view/autosize: True
- /rosdistro: kinetic
- /rosversion: 1.12.2
- /usb_cam/camera_frame_id: usb_cam
- /usb_cam/image_height: 480
- /usb_cam/image_width: 640
- /usb_cam/io_method: mmap
- /usb_cam/pixel_format: yuyv
- /usb_cam/video_device: /dev/video0

NODES
/
image_view (image_view/image_view)
usb_cam (usb_cam/usb_cam_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[usb_cam-1]: started with pid [9742]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [image_view/image_view]: can't locate node [image_view] in package [image_view]
[ INFO] [1469813059.142822397]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1469813059.142904972]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/submetu/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1469813059.142970068]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/submetu/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1469813059.142995991]: Camera calibration file /home/submetu/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1469813059.143027047]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video0) at 640x480 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS
[ERROR] [1469813064.141746901]: VIDIOC_S_FMT error 5, Input/output error
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error >'
what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
[usb_cam-1] process has died [pid 9742, exit code -6, cmd /home/submetu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/home/submetu/.ros/log/1fd73732-55ad-11e6-a65d-d8fc93edb7dc/usb_cam-1.log].
log file: /home/submetu/.ros/log/1fd73732-55ad-11e6-a65d-d8fc93edb7dc/usb_cam-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

I tried the tutorial of http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration , but I am not getting any camera output because the above error comes everytime. So I cant calibrate i.e. i cant get the head_camera.yaml file.
I looked at many tutorials but I could not find anything helpful to me.

Please help :(

Thank you in advance
(im using a lenovo thinkpad e440 with ubuntu. My camera is a logitech camera(it is connected as cheese is giving video output))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240684/usb_cam-package-and-head_camera.yaml-missing/) by [submetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27639/submetu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem by installing Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS indigo. Apparently usb_cam package is not working on ROS kinetic.
Also ROS indigo doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 so I had to downgrade to 12.04 for that.

I'm still getting calibration errors but there are online tutorials to calibrate it. I'm getting video output now on Rviz so i can calibrate it.

---

Originally posted by [submetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27639/submetu/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2016-08-01**:
Hi! no need for downgrading, usb_cam hadn't been added to ROS Kinetic repositories yet, but you can install it from source by following the step-by-step commands as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/197651/how-to-install-a-driver-like-usb_cam/).

**Comment by [submetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27639/submetu/) on 2016-08-02**:
Hi, the installation was not a problem. It installed just fine. I was receiving errors when i ran rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node or the roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch commands.
The system would quit after giving a bunch of errors. I listed the errors above in my question.

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2016-08-02**:
I see. I submitted an issue in their repository once asking them to fix the compatibility with Kinetic, but they didn't fix anything.

**Comment by [submetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27639/submetu/) on 2016-08-02**:
fingers crossed :)